# Issue using cblas_dgemm to compute pseudoinverse

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, lapack, intel-mkl

I am trying to compute the pseudoinverse of a matrix stored in `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR` layout using Intel MKL.

```
A_5x4 =
     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12
    13    14    15    16
    17    18    19    20
```

I am using `gesvd` function to compute the compact form of the SVD:

```
info = LAPACKE_dgesvd(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'S', 'S', m, n, A, lda, s, u, ldu, vt, ldvt, superb);
```

where `m=5`, `n=4`, `lda=4`, `ldu=5`, `ldvt=4`. I can successfully use MKL function to get the SVD of the matrix, `A = U*S*VT`:

```
u_5x4 = 
     0.0965          0.7686          0.6323          0.0034
     0.2455          0.4896         -0.6208          0.0412
     0.3945          0.2107         -0.3285         -0.4681
     0.5435         -0.0683         -0.0097          0.7989
     0.6924         -0.3472          0.3267         -0.3754

s_4x1 = 
    53.520222
     2.363426
     0.000000
     0.000000

vt_4x4 = 
     0.4430          0.4799          0.5167          0.5536
    -0.7097         -0.2640          0.1816          0.6273
     0.0912         -0.5242          0.7747         -0.3417
     0.5401         -0.6521         -0.3160          0.4280
```

Because `s` has only two non-zero elements, I need to consider the first two columns of `u`, and two columns of `v` (not `vt`) as well as the inverse of the elements of `s`

```
v_4x2_needed_for_pinv = 
     0.4430    0.4799
    -0.7097   -0.2640
     0.0912   -0.5242
     0.5401   -0.6521

u_2x5_needed_for_pinv = 
     0.0965   0.2455   0.3945   0.5435   0.6924
     0.7686   0.4896   0.2107  -0.0683  -0.3472
```

I can perform the matrix multiplication with `for-loop` with no problem and compute the pseudoinverse of A. However, I am very interested to use `dscal` and `cblas_dgemm` mainly because the actual matrix whose inverse is going to be computed is very large.

I was able to successfully figure out using `dscal` and multiply the first two columns of V by the inverse of S:

```
MKL_INT  k = ((m) < (n) ? (m) : (n));
// Computing VT = vt*(s^-1)
MKL_INT incx = 1;
MKL_INT r = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    double ss;
    if (s[i] > 1.0e-9)
    {
        ss = 1.0 / s[i];
        r++;
    }
    else
        ss = s[i];
    dscal(&n, &ss, &vt[i*n], &incx); // this replaces vt with new values.
    }
```

My issue is to perform the matrix multiplication `v_4x2_needed_for_pinv` with `u_2x5_needed_for_pinv`, which are a subset of `u` and `vt` arrays that `LAPACKE_dgesvd` has calculated. Could someone kindly help me figure out how to use `cblas_dgemm`? I would appreciate it.

I tried the following, the input to the function makes all sense to me but it does not work

```
// inv(A) = VT^T * U^T = V * U^T
double* inva = (double*)malloc(n*m * sizeof(double));
double alpha = 1.0, beta = 0.0;
MKL_INT ld_inva = n;
cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, CblasTrans, n, m, r, alpha, vt, n, u, m, beta, inva, ld_inva);
```

where `r=2` because `s` has two non-zero elements only (`53.520222` and `2.363426`).

Comment: _"I need to consider the first two columns of u, and two columns of v (not vt)."_ In the following example, you are putting the first two columns of `u` into `u_2x5` (transposed), but into `v_4x2`, you are putting the first two columns of `vt4x4`. Why such discrepancy?

Comment: To be more efficient, I actually do not store `v_4x2_needed_for_pinv` in a separate variable. All I have is the arrays that are resulted from `LAPACKE_dgesvd`.  I need to perform the final matrix multiplication on a subset of  `u` and `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the last three singular values are zero, we can say that the SVD produces :

- `u(5,2)` with `ldu=4`
- `vt(2,4)` with `ldvt=4`
- `invA(5,4)`

The inverse is computed as
    invA = vt^T * invS * u^T
and following your loop can be converted to
    invA = (invS * vt)^T * u^T

```
MKL_INT ma = mu = 5;
MKL_INT na = nvt = 4;
MKL_INT nu = mvt = ms = 2;

MKL_INT lda = ldu = ldvt = 4;

// vt = (invS * vt)
for(MKL_INT i=0; i<ms; i++){
  cblas_dscal (nvt, s[i], vt+(i*ldvt), 1);
}

// invA = vt^T * u^T
cblas_dgemm (CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, CblasTrans, ma, na, nu, 1.0, vt, ldvt, u, ldu, 0.0, invA, lda);
```